# Changing div visibility with z-index

Tags: jquery, z-index, modal-dialog

I'm working on a 1-page website. I've got several HTML5 videos that are hidden by default and when clicking on a link they are displayed in a overlay (modal) box.

At the moment I'm just showing and hiding them with JS however the "display: none;" on page load seems to cause an issue with the controls of the video once it's been revealed...

So to avoid hiding the videos altogether I thought instead to rearrange them behind the main content and bring each one to the front by using z-index. I'm not concerned about z-index issues with old browsers.

is there an easy way to do this with JQuery or would I have to write a custom function?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the z-index property with jQuery easily:

```
$('#video1').css('z-index', '10');
```

Make sure you're firing the jQuery once the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery to set the zIndex

$('#video1').css('zIndex', '100');

Answer (score 0):

try

```
visibility:hidden;
```

instead of

```
display:none;
```